# ipv6 static routing is not working

Tags: networking, routes

wondering ipv6 static route default route nothing working, only can ping the directly connected interface, but sh run command gave the static routes which I created to other networks,
but on the sh run output I saw the autoconfig static route which I created to obtain global unicast addresses and on the next line I saw the static route which i created to reach remote network,
Any ideas? I cant see any successful ping to remote network

3 routers in a row, routerA, routerB, routerC, connected via fastethernet. middle router B had it's ipv6 address configured manually and other two routes receive global unicast address through ipv6 address autoconfig command

here is the "Sh run" output of router A

```
version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!

hostname Router
!

! 
!

!
!

ipv6 unicast-routing
!

!
!

!
!

!
!

!
!

!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!

!
!

!
interface FastEthernet0/0
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
ipv6 address autoconfig
ipv6 enable
!

interface FastEthernet0/1
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
shutdown
!

interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!

ip classless
!

ipv6 route 2001:DB6:3C4D:1::/64 FastEthernet0/0 FE80::200:CFF:FE4A:AC01
ipv6 route 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::/64 FastEthernet0/0

THE SH RUN OUTPUT OF ROUTER C

Building configuration...

Current configuration : 660 bytes
!

version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!

hostname Router
!

!
!

!
!

ipv6 unicast-routing
!

!
!

!
!

!
!

!
!

!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!

!
!

!
interface FastEthernet0/0
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
ipv6 address autoconfig
ipv6 enable
!

interface FastEthernet0/1
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
shutdown
!

interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!

ip classless
!

ipv6 route 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::/64 FastEthernet0/0 FE80::200:CFF:FE4A:AC02
ipv6 route 2001:DB6:3C4D:1::/64 FastEthernet0/0
!

!
!

!
!

!
line con 0
!

line aux 0
!

line vty 0 4
login
!

!
!

end
```

Why both does not ping! I have defined the ipv6 static route for both at there

```
Router A routing table

Router#sh ipv6 route 
IPv6 Routing Table - 4 entries
Codes: C - Connected, L - Local, S - Static, R - RIP, B - BGP
U - Per-user Static route, M - MIPv6
I1 - ISIS L1, I2 - ISIS L2, IA - ISIS interarea, IS - ISIS summary   
O - OSPF intra, OI - OSPF inter, OE1 - OSPF ext 1, OE2 - OSPF ext 2
ON1 - OSPF NSSA ext 1, ON2 - OSPF NSSA ext 2
D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external
C 2001:DB6:3C4D:1::/64 [0/0]
via ::, FastEthernet0/0
L   2001:DB6:3C4D:1:260:5CFF:FEA8:3A01/128 [0/0]
via ::, FastEthernet0/0
S 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::/64 [1/0]
via ::, FastEthernet0/0
L FF00::/8 [0/0]
via ::, Null0
Router#
```

router C routing table

```
Router#sh ipv6 route 
IPv6 Routing Table - 4 entries
Codes: C - Connected, L - Local, S - Static, R - RIP, B - BGP
U - Per-user Static route, M - MIPv6
I1 - ISIS L1, I2 - ISIS L2, IA - ISIS interarea, IS - ISIS summary
O - OSPF intra, OI - OSPF inter, OE1 - OSPF ext 1, OE2 - OSPF ext 2
ON1 - OSPF NSSA ext 1, ON2 - OSPF NSSA ext 2   
D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external
S 2001:DB6:3C4D:1::/64 [1/0] 
via ::, FastEthernet0/0
C 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::/64 [0/0]
via ::, FastEthernet0/0
L 2001:DB6:3C4D:2:290:CFF:FE49:7601/128 [0/0]
via ::, FastEthernet0/0
L FF00::/8 [0/0]
via ::, Null0
```

there static route is defined and why it's not pinging!

middle router B configuration

```
Router#sh run
Building configuration..

Current configuration : 590 bytes
!

version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!

hostname Router
!

!
!

!
!

ipv6 unicast-routing
!

!
!

!
!

!
!

!
!

!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!

!
!

!
interface FastEthernet0/0
no  ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
ipv6 address 2001:DB6:3C4D:1::1/64
ipv6 enable
!

interface FastEthernet0/1
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
ipv6 address 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::1/64
ipv6 enable   
!

interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!

ip classless
!

!
!

!
!

!
!

line con 0
!

line aux 0
!

line vty 0 4
login
!

!
!

end
```

why router A and C are not pinging!

Answer (score 0):

As Cisco official book mentions bellow

> To configure a static route that uses an Ethernet interface, the ipv6 route command’s forwarding parameters should always include a next-hop IPv6 address. IOS allows you to configure the ipv6 route command using only the outgoing-interface parameter, without listing
> a next-hop address. The router will accept the command; however, if that outgoing interface
> happens to be an Ethernet interface, the router cannot successfully forward IPv6 packets
> using the route.

So you can not basically use the config in your router with only specifying the interface you should use a unicast ipv6 address too.
So edit the config of Router A at line bellow

```
ipv6 route 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::/64 FastEthernet0/0
```

To something like this

```
ipv6 route 2001:DB6:3C4D:2::/64 FastEthernet0/0 FE80::200:CFF:FE4A:AC01
```